# SailsJS: best place to extend Javascript objects using prototype inheritance

Tags: express, sails.js

I am using **Sails JS** (an MVC Express JS framework)

I want to add functions to existing Javascript classes like Date class, for example:

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function () {
    var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7);
}
```

Is **config/bootstrap.js** considered the best place to add this code? 
If not, what is the best place to add it?

I am trying to call it as less as I have to and always expect that function will be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **config/bootstrap.js** is a fine place to add this code.

Long answer: **config/bootstrap.js** is a fine place to add this code, but you shouldn't be extending native Javascript objects like this unless you *really* need to and have done all your homework and are sure that it won't conflict with / break any other packages.  You could easily move this utility into a [service](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Services), or use an existing date utility module like [Moment](http://moment.js) that as already [done this for you](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/).  With [tests](http://momentjs.com/tests/).